# How to add data to Gridview using specific field name searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, webforms

I have a program in which I need to display the search result in gridview. Here is my code.
Here @search1 is one of my sql field name. My sql field names are bra1,bra2,bra3,bra4.
If I type CODE in text box as eg "a103" as search and from dropdownlist I have select the
 branch as bra1 as search1, then in gridview it will show all the values of CODE "a103" in
 bra1. Here the a103 is example of my item code and bra1 is the field name. So give me a 
solution for this.For the place "search1" I can select any field name value bra1,bra2 or bra3
and the rsult will be shown in gridview.Important: bra1 is the field name in sql or column name.
 here is my code:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
 {          
    String str = " Select CODE,@search1 From OthStk Where CODE='a103';";    
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);     
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search1",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=DropDownList2.SelectedValue;         
     con.Open();         
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();     
     da.SelectCommand = xp;
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds,"BranchCode");   
     GridView2.DataSource = ds;
     GridView2.DataBind();
     con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I'm unsure what your actual question is. Are you getting the wrong result? Also you might want to do a using(con.open) { //code } instead of open closing it manually. Or at least try catch the operation before the close so you don't end up with open connections when something goes wrong.

Comment: I need to get the result like this, if I select bra1 then result will be            in table as   CODE bra1
a103  2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi Vishnu,**

Your question is not bit cleared but as i understand from your question is that you have one dropdown which contain column name and one textbox in which you serach the criteria.

You should directly concatenate dropdown value in your str.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
     {          
        String str = " Select CODE," + DropDownList2.SelectedValu+ " From OthStk Where CODE='a103';";    

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(your connection)
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);     
         con.Open();         
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();     
         da.SelectCommand = xp;
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds,"BranchCode");   
         GridView2.DataSource = ds;
         GridView2.DataBind();
         con.Close();
     }
```